# How to prevent white screen during initial loading of React app?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, frontend, web-deployment

```
function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <div
        style={{
          width: "100vw",
          height: "100vh",
          display: "flex",
          alignItems: "center",
          justifyContent: "center",
          backgroundColor: "black",
        }}
      >
        <Logo3 />
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

The App is as simple as above. The background is supposed to be black, but sometimes there is an initial white screen that appears for a split second before the app is loaded. How this white screen be prevent?

Answer (score 1):

So the easiest way to do this is to just set a background color for the body of your page within your html-file. This way there is an initial background color and you won't experience the flash when (re-)loading the website.

```
<style>
    body {
      background-color: black;
    }
</style>
```

The other more complex solution is to use server-side-rendering.
The idea is to let the server serve an initial version of the DOM.
This DOM will be diffed and altered by react after all the JavaScript code is loaded and evaluated.

Take a look at

```
ReactDOMServer.renderToString(reactElement)
```

and

```
ReactDOM.hydrate()
```

if you are using a Node-Backend.